# Where to put all code/organize code in unity?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture, unity-game-engine

so I am a beginner at unity and cannot grasp how you are supposed to have a pattern or architecture with unity.

I am currently making a platform game which has a character that is supposed to stay on moving platforms and not fall off the screen (very basic). On the platform there are "monsters". If you touch these monsters you also lose. There is also some trees and such on the platform.

This is what I have so far:
In the "manual gameobject list" or whatever you call it:
Directional light

Main camera

Background (just a sprite that is always showing)

Player (contains a JS script that has character specific code for jumping and such)

Platformspawner (Contains only a c# script. This script spawns multiple platform gameobjects, these gameobjects then use a script called platform.cs. This class spawns monsters and the trees on each platform. The monsters and trees each use their own c# file that keeps track of collisions and such.)

For me this is pretty obvious code and I do not know how to organize it much better. Any tips? I tried following an MVC tutorial but it seems like there is not much gameobject spawning in those tutorials which is what I have to do, so they confuse me.

Comment: Honestly, the way you have your code set up right now seems pretty solid. In the games I make, I'll often have a SceneManager empty gameobject that will usually handle running the scene while individual objects control themselves. My best tip is to spread out the code. If possible, let individual gameobjects handle themselves while one large script keeps track of them all. Keep individual scripts focused on achieving one goal. But you seem to have a good system set up right now

Answer (score 0):

Your hierarchy (the area of the editor where all of your GameObjects are stored) looks pretty solid. You typically don't need much organization in there if your program is pretty small, but of course putting things into folders (for example, putting multiple canvases into a large Canvas folder) can't hurt.

As for your project, where all of your assets are stored, I believe that folders are paramount for good organization, because if you combine all of your assets it'll be hard to distinguish them. I recommend having base folders for different types of assets (/Scripts/, /Materials/, /Prefabs/, etc.) and storing individual assets in there (and of course adding more folders as you see fit). You should almost never have to have an asset directly in the /Assets/ folder.

Of course, that is only my opinion and my method of organization. Everyone has a different method of managing their project, but what I've described above is the basic system of organization. Happy coding!